# multiple forms not submitting correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, opencart

I'm working in OpenCart MVC and I have a page that has a main form called campaign. there is a secondary form called components. the component form allows for multiple instances of itself(click add another component shows). The idea is that a campaign can have infinite components and on submit the campaign info will be written to the campaign table and the component info will be written to the component table. well that is not happening. currently when i fill out both forms and submit. the info for campaign form is written to the table. however in the component table a new record is made but its all blank. Why are the values not being added? Furthermore, additional components seem to not get written at all. so if you start a campaign and add three components then submit only one new(blank) record will be written in components.

MODEL:

```
public function addCampaign($data) {

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns SET campaign_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_name']) . "', campaign_giving_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_goal']
        . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['code']) . "', campaign_active = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_active']) . "', campaign_giving_count_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_count_goal']
        . "', campaign_owner = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_owner']). "', date_beginning = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_beginning']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "'");

        $this->cache->delete('campaign');

        return $campaign_id;
    }

    public function addComponent($data) {

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign_components SET component_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['component_name']) . "', component_date = '" . $data['component_date']
         . "', component_owner = '" . $this->db->escape($data['component_owner']). "', campaign_code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_code']) . "'");

        $this->cache->delete('campaign');

        return $campaign_id;
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function add() {
        $this->load->language('campaigns/campaign');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('campaigns/campaign');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) {

            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->addCampaign($this->request->post);
            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->addComponent($this->request->post);
            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('campaigns/campaign', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true));
        }

        $this->getForm();

    }
```

VIEW:

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-campaign" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForms()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
      </div>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_form; ?></h3>

      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-campaign" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-general">

                <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="language<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>">
                  <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                      <label class="control-label" for="input-campaign-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
                      <input type="text" name="campaign_name" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-campaign-name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campaign_name; ?>" />
                      <?php if (isset($error_name[$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                      <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name[$language['language_id']]; ?></div>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" ><?php echo $entry_owner; ?></label>
                        <select name="campaign_owner" id="campaign_owner" value="<?php echo $campaign_owner; ?>">
                        <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                      <label class="control-label" for="input-campaign-goal"><?php echo $entry_goal; ?></label>
                      <input type="text" name="campaign_giving_goal" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_goal; ?>" id="input-campaign-goal" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campaign_giving_goal; ?>" />
                      <?php if (isset($error_name[$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                      <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name[$language['language_id']]; ?></div>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                      <label class="control-label" for="input-campaign-goal"><?php echo $entry_goal_count; ?></label>
                      <input type="text" name="campaign_giving_count_goal" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_goal_count; ?>" id="input-campaign-goal-count" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campaign_giving_count_goal; ?>" />
                      <?php if (isset($error_name[$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                      <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name[$language['language_id']]; ?></div>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                      <label class="control-label" for="input-date-beginning"><?php echo $entry_campaign_start_date; ?></label>
                        <div class="input-group date required">
                          <input type="text" name="date_beginning"  placeholder="<?php echo  $entry_date; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" id="input-date-beginning" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $date_beginning; ?>" readonly />
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                          </span>
                    </div>
                    <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                      <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_date_starting; ?></label>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input-date-ending"><?php echo $entry_campaign_end_date; ?></label>
                      <div class="input-group date required">
                      <input type="text" name="date_ending"  placeholder="<?php echo  $entry_campaign_end_date; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" id="input-date-ending" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $date_ending; ?>" readonly />
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                      <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_date_starting; ?></label>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input-code"><?php echo $entry_code; ?></label>
                      <div class="input-code required">
                      <input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $code; ?>" id="input-code" class="form-control" readonly />
                    </div>
                    <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                      <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_code; ?></label>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input-active"><?php echo $entry_active; ?></label>
                    <select name="campaign_active" id="input-"active" class="form-control">
                      <option value="*"><?php echo $text_active; ?></option>
                      <?php if ($filter_campaign_active) { ?>
                      <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>
                      <?php } else { ?>
                      <option value="1"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                      <?php if (!$filter_campaign_active && !is_null($filter_campaign_active)) { ?>
                      <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>
                      <?php } else { ?>
                      <option value="0"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  </div>

                                </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>

        </form>
        </div>
  </div>
            </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="launch"><?php echo $text_add_component ?></button>
<div class="wrapper">
          <div class="panel panel-default" id="add-components">

            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_add_component; ?></h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="addon">
              <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-components" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">

                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-general">

                      <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="language<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>">
                        <div class="form-group required">
                          <div class= "row">
                          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-1 form-group required" >
                            <label for="input-name<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
                            <input type="text" name="component_name" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" class="form-control" />

                            <?php if (isset($error_name[$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                            <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name[$language['language_id']]; ?></div>
                            <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                            <div class="campaign-group form-group">

                                  <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="button-type" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><?php echo $text_filter_type;?><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                    <ul class="campaign-form-type dropdown-menu">
                                      <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Direct Mail</li>
                                      <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Email</li>
                                      <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Event</li>
                                      <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Text Message</li>
                                      <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Letter</li>
                                      <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Postcard</li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                          <label class="control-label" for="input-date-beginning"><?php echo $entry_campaign_start_date; ?></label>
                            <div class="input-group date required">
                              <input type="text" name="date_beginning"  placeholder="<?php echo  $entry_date; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" id="input-date-beginning" class="form-control" />
                              <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                            <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                              <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_date_starting; ?></label>
                            <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                              <label class="control-label" ><?php echo $entry_owner; ?></label>
                              <select name="campaign_owner" id="component_owner">
                              <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option>
                              <?php } ?>
                              </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                            <!--label class="control-label" for="input-code"><?php echo $entry_code; ?></label-->
                              <div class="input-code required">
                              <input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $code; ?>" id="input-code" class="form-control" readonly />
                            </div>
                            <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                              <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_code; ?></label>
                            <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>
                    </form>
</div>

                </div>
                <div class="cancel-save">
                  <button type="submit" form="form-campaign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForms(0)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                  <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
                </div>
</div>

        </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/summernote/summernote.js"></script>
  <link href="view/javascript/summernote/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/summernote/opencart.js"></script>


  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#input-code').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#input-example1').val('<?php echo $store; ?>?tracking=' + $('#input-code').val());
  $('#input-example2').val('<?php echo $store; ?>index.php?route=common/home&tracking=' + $('#input-code').val());
});

$('#input-code').trigger('keyup');
//--></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('launch').onclick = function() {
        var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');
    var container = document.getElementById('add-components')
        var clonedNode = addOnDiv.cloneNode(true);
          container.appendChild(clonedNode );
      }


  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
  submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("form-campaign").submit();
    document.getElementById("form-components").submit();
}
</script>



  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    formatDate:'yyyy-mm-dd',
        pickTime: false
});

$('.time').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false,
    icons: {
            up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
            down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
            },
});

$('.datetime').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: true,
    pickTime: true
});
//--></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#language a:first').tab('show');
$('#option a:first').tab('show');
//--></script></div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: how are you submitting them? Via ajax? With a normal postback you can only submit one form at a time from a page.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"><!--
  submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("form-campaign").submit();
    document.getElementById("form-components").submit();
}
</script>

Comment: Yes, that will just submit the first form. That causes a postback, so at that point the page refreshes. Therefore, no further code on the current page is executed. Therefore, the second form won't get submitted. You either need to combine this into one `<form>`, or use ajax to submit them within the context of the running page.

Comment: Hi, so I dont think I can combine the form so Im looking into ajax solutions not really sure how to do that I tried this and it creates a few blank rows in each table, any suggestions?                 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('form').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $.post(that.attr('action'), that.serialize());
});
</script>

Comment: I can't say just from that little bit of code really. Would need proper debugging info about the content and response from each request, tracking the number of database calls made and what queries were executed etc. All stuff you can (and should) do yourself when trying to diagnose these kinds of problems. Also that code in your comment looks like it would execute when the page loads, not when the form submission is triggered by the user. That could be a reason for blank records.